# Spring pointcut designators differences (within vs execution)

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, pointcut

Please... can anybody explain me what are the differences between using the following spring pointcut designators?

Using "within pointcut designator":

```
<aop:pointcut expression="within(my.app.dao.impl.*)" id="commonDaoOperation"/>
```

Using "execution pointcut designator":

```
<aop:pointcut expression="execution(public * my.app.dao.impl.*.*(..))" id="commonDaoOperation"/>
```

I am using the second one in my web-projects (and I think it's the most used), the problem i have found with this approach is that it's consuming a lot of memory in the heap...

After analyzing the "heap dump" of the application server with the "eclipse memory analyzer" i have found that my application is consuming 450 MB and the instances of the class `"org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut`" are consuming 30% of those 450MB...

Each instance of `AspectJExpressionPointcut` occupy 6 MB (approximately) and this is because each instance mantains a cache of matches with instances of java.lang.reflect.Method and surprisingly there are a lot of java methods cached (methods that my pointcut expression doesnt mentions).

After Reading Spring Documentation, I decided to use the first one approach (within pointcut designator) and now each instance of `AspectJExpressionPointcut` occupy much less memory.

The question is about that... what is the difference in performance between them...

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9):

The [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts) explains the difference:

> - **execution** - for matching method execution join points, this is the primary pointcut designator you will use when working with Spring AOP
> - **within** - limits matching to join points within certain types (simply the execution of a method declared within a matching type when
>     using Spring AOP)

In other words, `execution` matches a method and `within` matches a type.

In this case, your pointcuts are pretty much equivalent. Your `within` matches any type in the package `my.app.dao.impl` and your `execution` matches all the public methods of any type in the package `my.app.dao.impl`.

However, `execution` is implemented, I think, with an interceptor for each matched method (a lot of objects), which `within` only needs one interceptor since it matches the entire type (very little objects).

Comment: Thanks Sotirios Delimanolis,

Can i use them together without any problems?

Recently I have changed my configuration to use them together (within and execution)... something like the following:

    '<'aop:pointcut expression="within(my.app.dao.impl.*) AND execution(public * my.app.dao.impl.*.*(..))"


And the memory consumption of instances of class "AspectJExpressionPointcut" was reduced very much!

So Is this recommended to use them together?

Comment: @glazaror There's no real point using them together. The `within` already matches everything in your `execution`.

Comment: Ok Sotirios Delimanolis, you have the reason... I should only use the "within".

Comment: In my "use case" the instances of "AspectJExpressionPointcut" were the problem in memory consumption because of "execution pointcut designator"... changing that for "within pointcut designator" reduces that problem.

Comment: So... can it be considered better to use within pointcut designator in some use cases?

Comment: @glazaror It's not _better_. Each has its own purpose. For what you are trying to achieve, `within` is more suitable.

Comment: glazaror: Regarding your first comment, I would say @SotiriosDelimanolis threw you off the right track there. As per the Spring AOP [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html): *The existing designators naturally fall into one of three groups: kinded, scoping and context: **1) Kinded designators** are those which select a particular kind of join point. For example: `execution`, `get`, `set`; **2) Scoping designators** are those which select a group of join points of interest (of probably many kinds). For example: `within`, `withincode`;*

Comment: glazaror: The Spring AOP [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) then goes on to say: *A well written pointcut should try and include at least the first two types (**kinded** AND **scoping**), whilst the **contextual designators** may be included if wishing to match based on join point context, or bind that context for use in the advice. Supplying either JUST a **kinded designator** or JUST a **contextual designator** will work but could affect weaving performance (time and memory used) due to all the extra processing and analysis.*

Comment: So to sum up: seems as if using BOTH the `execution` and `within` designators in your example isn't that redundant after all.

Answer (score 1):

execution() matches join points that are method executions. This is the only designator that actually performs matches. All other designators (supported by Spring AOP) only limit those matches. 
Note that Spring supports only a subset of designators available in AspectJ (Spring AOP is proxy-based). 
AspectJ pointcut designators that are supported in Spring are:
args() and @args(), target() and @target(), within() and @within(), execution(), this(), @annotation

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://reflectoring.io/aop-spring/):

- `execution()` - match a joinPoint method’s signature
- `within()` - match all the JoinPoint methods in a given class, package, or sub-package

---

Other existing types of pointcut expressions: `args()`, `target()`, `this()`, `@args()`, `@within()`, `@target()`, `@annotation()`